# Determining the magnetic reluctance of a straight flux path

Tags: electromagnetism

Currently I run into an issue understanding the following. The bottom part of this magnetic circuit is made from steel which has a finite relative permeability. However, the flux paths is made out of 3 parts, namely lt1, lt2 and lt3.

How could I determine the magnetic reluctance of the bottom part of the circuit since it is made of 3 parts.

Can I add the flux paths lt1, lt2 and lt3 and use ht as width, or do I have to do it in parts?

[image]